# How to add a field for each taxonomy term or entity reference chosen in Content Type?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, nodes, entities

I have a content type ‘Product’. When the user add a product it is necessary to choose a Store (a taxonomy term or another content type). After stores are chosen, it is necessary to add the directly url to that product in that store. More than on store is selectable and he could add or remove another. There are more data in Store type.

It is something like one to multiple to one for each I think…

```
Product01   > Store 1 > URL01 
            > Store 2 > URL02

Product02   > Store 1  > URL03
            > Store 10 > URL04
```

My options are:

1) Create a field with multiple values. So if the user choose 3 stores he adds 3 fields to that link.
Problem: It is not directly associate and if he changes orders it will associate de wrong url and chaos will happen.

2) Using Conditionals field (Taxonomy Term)
Problem I could not make it work with multiple selected store and for each new term I need to create a specified field.

3) Entity Reference (Content Type)
Can’t find a way to associate multiple select to adicional fields.

X) Rules?
Too much crazy for me, could not even begin thinking with that…

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Answer is Field Collection Module (https://drupal.org/project/field_collection). There is another called Multifield, you could try (https://drupal.org/project/multifield).

After installed, edit your content type and add an field with field type Field Collection. Go to Structure>Field Collection and there add fields to the Field Collection created in your content type.

After that it is equal to adding a field with reference term to content type.

What this Video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1V1ofpgUw-Y